# Ember.js: Loading related models directly

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I dont understand how ember loads related models.

Lets say thats my model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  states: DS.hasMany('state', {async: true})
})
```

I load this on of my outer routes. When navigating though an ember-app (into nested routes), model-contexts are often provided for routes not by the model-hook of the route but with the link-to helper (when using dynamic-segments, the model-hook will be ignored). When the target route has something in its template like `{{#each model.states as |state|}}`, ember will load automatically the related model-entrys from (in that case)the state-model. (How and why? - Just because of the `each` in the template?

When accesing an dynamic-route directly, the model is not given and the model-hook of the dynamic route will be called. So loading my model is easy: just override the model hook and load record with the url parameter (`return this.store.find('item', {title: params.item_title})`). But no related models will be loaded. How can I do that manually and what (and when) is the way ember do it by default?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## How does Ember know to automatically fetch relationships?

ember-data allows you to define relationships (currently only `belongsTo` and `hasMany`) with `async` option set to `true` or `false`. Based on this option, after fetching the model from the API (via `find` method), ember-data will expect relationships object either directly in the response JSON or not. You have `async: true` (which is rather a common and supported way of handling relationships), therefore ember-data assumes that in your JSON response it gets the `id`s of states, but not necesseraily the states themselves.

If you define your `hasMany` as `async: true`, it **always** returns promise. It means, that if you make something like this:

```
this.get("item").get("states")[0]
```

Will not work, as `get("states")` will not return an array, but the promise to fetch this array. However, Handlebars are smart (as the `get` and `set` methods of Ember) and it can find out what is a promise and wait for it to resolve before using it content. Therefore if your template contains:

```
{{#each model.states as |state|}}
```

Handlebars finds out that `states` is promise, wait for it to resolve, and after resolve they use its content as an array. Very similar behaviour can be found using `belongsTo` method. Assuming that your `item` has one `state`, if you use the code as follows:

```
this.get("item.state.somePropertyOfState")
```

Even if you did not fetched the `state` and currently you don't know what is the `somePropertyOfState` value, ember `get` will find out it's a promise and fetch it for you automatically.

## How can I manually fetch relationships?

There are couple of ways to do it.

First one is to explicitly fetch them in ember code:

```
this.get("item.states").then(function(states) {
  # now you have fetched the states that the item has, and moreover
  # they are accessible in states variable
});
```

Second, you can let Ember do it automatically for you as I described formerly (e.g. via template).

Third, you can send the relationships with your response using a mechanism called sideload. This will significantly reduce the number of API requests. When you allow ember fetch your relationships, ember is performing one request per one relationship object, which means that if you have ten `states` that belongs to `item`, the API will be hit ten times. However, if you sidelod the `states` while fetching the `item`, the request will be sent only once. [Take a look here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships) to get more info about that.

Sorry for a long post, but I hope that I clarifed a bit.

Comment: Well thank you a lot! Very helpfull ideed. But you say that ember loads automatically if some value gonna used in the template. Well in my app it dont!
- Loaded a model
- Link-to a nested route
- using something like {{model.relatedrecords.title}} in that template
- nothing happend (not even a rest request)

(lets say my first loaded model got an member like relatedrecords {hasmany to another model } )

Comment: Change .than -> .then

Comment: Using the first way, how could you then iterate through the states?

Comment: states variable, that is available in your promise handler, can be iterated as an array.